# Nested form returns undefined method `with_indifferent_access'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a student model and a referee model. I want the student to fill out a form, that has a nested area which requests the information to contact the referee. I'm using activeadmin and formtastic with rails 3.2.6.

My issue is when I navigate to new_student_path, I get "undefined method `with_indifferent_access'"

students_controller.rb:

```
  def new
   @student = Student.new
   @student.referee = Referee.new
  end
```

student model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :referee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :referee
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :statement
attr_accessible :referee, :referee_attributes
alias_method :referee=, :referee_attributes=
```

Student's new.html.erb:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @student do |f| %>
<%= f.semantic_errors :state %>

 <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>

    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :referee do |ff| %>
        <% if h.object.new_record? %>
        <%= ff.inputs do %>
            <%= ff.input :firstname, :label => "Reference's First Name" %>
            <%= ff.input :lastname, :label => "Reference's Last Name"%>
            <%= ff.input :email, :label => "Reference's Email"%>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %
```

Comment: what is h? in new.html.erb- if h.object.new_record?

Comment: Haha I think that was a line I had from before that I forgot to take out, I removed it and I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace on the error and also the line of code throwing the error if not already posted here?

Comment: thank you so much for asking further questions, I managed to solve the error, I posted what I did below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made the following modifications and now it works.

student model:

```
has_one :referee
accepts_nested_attributes_for :referee
attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :statement
attr_accessible :referee, :referee_attributes
#alias_method :referee=, :referee_attributes= - removed this line (preventing method from being created)
```

Then removed the validation on the attributes that weren't displayed on the nested form and everything worked fine.

Also

```
@student.referee.build
```

Only works with a has_many association. So had to use

```
@student.referee = Referee.new
```

or

```
@student.build_referee
```

Comment: According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html it should work.

Comment: '@student.build_referee' works but '@student.referee.build' gives an undefined method 'build' error